# Cannot install pyenchant on OSX

Tags: python, macos, pyenchant

I am trying to install python bindings for the enchant library (pyenchant), according to the readme, it should be as simple as running `python setup.py install`
But when I try that, I get this error:

```
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './tools/pyenchant-bdist-osx-sources/build/lib'
```

Can someone tell me what to do? I have tried google, but with no luck.

PS: I have this same question on serverfault, as I thought that was the most appropriate place for it, but with little help there, I am now trying here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to install the [enchant](https://www.abisource.com/projects/enchant/) library first. On the download page [pyenchant](https://web.archive.org/web/20130123033756/http://packages.python.org:80/pyenchant/download.html) indicates that it is a prerequisite if you are building from source. (There are pre-build binaries listed for python 2.5 and  2.6 as well.)

I just installed enchant via [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) on OS X 10.7 and then pyenchant installed without a problem.

If you decide to use homebrew for installing enchant, note that I had to brew install `pkg-config` separate as the recipe doesn't seem to install it as a dependancy (and fails as a result).

Comment: Still working as of 10.10 Yosemite: `brew install enchant; pip install pyenchant`

Comment: Is it possible to use pyenchant with Python 3.4?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll need to install
the Apple Developer Tools (XCode)
for your Mac OS X version.

If you haven't done so...

cheers
James

Comment: Hi, already have them. Sucks to download more than 1 GB, just to get a few hundred KB of compiler.