# Having trouble with PyEnchant installation on El Capitan

Tags: python, installation, osx-elcapitan, pyenchant, enchant

It's possible I should just open this is an issue on the Enchant package, but it could definitely be something I'm missing too. I'm using El Capitan and python 2.7. I tried a few things:

`pip install penchant` seems to successfully install pyenchant-1.6.6, but when I try to `import enchant` I get the error `ImportError: The 'enchant' C library was not found. Please install it via your OS package manager, or use a pre-built binary wheel from PyPI.` I followed the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29381919/importerror-the-enchant-c-library-was-not-found-please-install-it-via-your-o) and upgraded pip.

I followed the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683181/cannot-install-pyenchant-on-osx) and started with `brew install enchant`, but that gave the error

`curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
Error: Failed to download resource "glib--patch"
Download failed: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jacknagel/af332f42fae80c570a77/raw/7b5fd0d2e6554e9b770729fddacaa2d648327644/glib-hardcoded-paths.diff`

I also downloaded the wheel [here](https://pythonhosted.org/pyenchant/download.html) (second-to-last link) and tried to pip install it, but got the error that it `is not a supported wheel on this platform`.

Thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: i'm having the exact same problem. thanks for posting this question, and let's hope someone gets back soon